# Get last 2 numbers from string: 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5)'

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to grab numbers 3 and 5 from string like 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5)' my first thought was to use `.split()` on commas, but that would give me 3 with space and 5 with `)` as results, surely there must be cleaner way to grab them using regular expressions and split it that way? So no lengthy operations need to be performed in order to grab clean values.

Edit, string structure is always the same, only numbers change.

Comment: Is your string always containing the same number of values, or can you have strings like `matrix(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...)` ?

Comment: The regex to grab the last two numbers with 2 groups: `(\d+) *, *(\d+) *\) *$` with optional spaces around the commas and in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `slice`:

```
var s = 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5)';
var m = s.match(/\d+/g).slice(-2);
//=> ["3", "5"]
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to match numbers between `(...)` then use:

```
var m = s.replace(/^.*?\(([^)]+)\).*$/, '$1').match(/\d+/g).slice(-2)
//=> ["3", "5"]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5)';
var numbers = str
                .match(/\d+/g)  //["1", "0", "0", "1", "3", "5"] - get the numbers from the string
                .slice(-2)      //["3", "5"] - return the last two indexes of the4 array
                .map(Number);   //[3, 5] - convert the strings to numbers.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it (because it works :) )

```
function getMatrixArgs(str) {
  return new Function('matrix', 'return ' + s)(function matrix() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, -2);
  });
}
```

Then use it like

```
var matrixStr = 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5)';

console.log( getMatrixArgs(matrixStr) );
// [3, 5]
```

## Disclaimer

This is **not** safe if the value is unfiltered user-input. I am proposing this merely as an alternative to regular expressions. This code supports any "arguments" (ex: `'matrix(1, 0, 2, 3.35, 9.87739)'` or `'matrix("foo", "bar")'`, etc.).